# How can I make the Next button work in HTML?

Tags: html

Hello I am trying to make the next button work.

I want to go to next page after each image but apparently the button appears but doesn't work.

```
{% load otree static %}
{% load user_agents %}

{% block title %}
    Emivasa
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<div class="card bg-light m-3">

    <div class="card-body">
        
        <img src={% static "verde/1.PNG" %}/>
        
            {% next_button %}
            
        <img src={% static "verde/2.PNG" %}/>
            
            {% next_button %}
            
        <img src={% static "verde/3.PNG" %}/>   
            
            {% next_button %}
            
        <img src={% static "verde/4.PNG" %}/>   

        
    </div>
    
</div>

    {% next_button %}
<div class="card bg-light m-3">

    <div class="card-body">
        
        <img src={% static "verde/1.PNG" %}/>
        
            {% next_button %}
            
        <img src={% static "verde/2.PNG" %}/>
            
            {% next_button %}
            
        <img src={% static "verde/3.PNG" %}/>   
            
            {% next_button %}
            
        <img src={% static "verde/4.PNG" %}/>   

        
    </div>
    
</div>
    
    {% next_button %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried it out in bs4(bootstrap4).
Here is the code, try it out >>>

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>next buttons</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="code" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#code" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#code" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#code" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Image2" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="image3.jpg" alt="image3" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#code" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#code" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

hope it works

for more info visit>> https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_carousel.asp